# speed up R function

Tags: r

please can any one help me to make this function run faster:

```
st=c(0 ,0, 9,39,44 ,100, 0, 0, 8,26 ,100, 0, 0, 6, 9,16,20,24,29,35,37,47,54,73 ,100, 0, 0, 6,35,44 ,100, 0, 0,10,16,27,40,51,91, 100, 0, 0,3, 7,28,69,71,75, 100, 0, 0,19 ,100, 0, 0, 7,24,29,35 ,100, 0, 0, 8,11,14,15,18,31,32,33,50,53,56,62,79,80,82,87,88,89, 100, 0, 0, 2,7,31,34,40 ,100, 0, 0,10,41,51,76 ,100, 0, 0, 4,32,41,46 ,100, 0, 0,19,26,59,76,83,88,92 ,100, 0, 0,11,27,51, 100, 0, 0, 5, 7,45,56,78,3 ,100, 0, 0, 3,12,23,46,53,72 ,100)

id=c(1:length(st))
data=cbind(id,st)

a=gRbase::combnPrim(c(0:100), 4,  simplify = T)
c=a[,a[1,]==0]
 d=c[,c[4,]==100]
 list_d=c(unname(as.data.frame(d)))

  p=c()

f=function(dataf,dec,...){
    cc<-vector("list", 3)
    dataf=data.frame(dataf)
    for(j in 1:3){
        cc[[j]] <-c(dec[j],dec[j+1]);
        for(k in 1:nrow(dataf)){
            if(round(dataf[k,"st"],digits=3)>= round(cc[[j]][1],digits=3) && round(dataf[k,"st"],digits=3) <= round(cc[[j]][2],digits=3)){
                dataf[k,"p"]=j
            } 
        }
    }
    return(dataf)
}

l=vector("list",length(list_d))

library(doSNOW)
cluster = makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cluster)

system.time(l<-foreach(i= 1:length(list_d)) %dopar% f(data,list_d[[i]]))
stopCluster(cluster)
```

and this is the result the profiling  :

[image]

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you profiled the function and determined where the bottlenecks are? You did not provide data to run this in the first place.

Comment: please give us dataf and dec

Comment: What does the function do? What is the algorithm? You should get rid of the R loops and try to vectorize. Btw., don't try to profile a parallelized loop. The profiling doesn't see what happens on the workers. You should profile with `%do%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, your function determine in which interval some values are, dataf$st contains the values, and dec contains the values of the interval.

In this case this works:

```
# original function
f=function(dataf,dec,...){
  cc<-vector("list", 3)  
  dataf=data.frame(dataf)
  for(j in 1:3){
    cc[[j]] <-c(dec[j],dec[j+1]);
    for(k in 1:nrow(dataf)){
      if(round(dataf[k,"st"],digits=3)>= round(cc[[j]][1],digits=3) && round(dataf[k,"st"],digits=3) <= round(cc[[j]][2],digits=3)){          
        dataf[k,"p"]=j
      } 
    }
  }
  return(dataf)
}

# my proposal
f2=function(dataf,dec,...){
  dec <- round(dec,digits=3)
  dataf=data.frame(dataf)
  dataf$p <- sapply(round(dataf$st,digits=3), function(x){match(TRUE,x<dec)-1})
  dataf$p[dataf$p==0] <- NA
  return(dataf)
}

dec <- 1:4
df1 <- data.frame(st = sample(1:50000,1000)/10000,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
original <- f(df1,dec)
new      <- f2(df1,dec)
all.equal(original,new) # TRUE, results are the same

# now let's check the speed
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(original = f(df1,dec),
               new = f2(df1,dec),
               times = 10)

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
# original 82.025627 82.600381 84.834773 84.059917 86.214891 89.83188    10
# new       2.115691  2.142234  2.234287  2.192843  2.289462  2.49650    10
```

40 times faster